# C - Getting a struct from a function by pointer - segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm fairly new with C, and I'm having a great deal of trouble with this one function. I have a struct declared as:

```
struct nivel {
    size_t filas;
    size_t columnas;
    int **mapa;
};
```

It's just a 2d array, with it's size info. Now, I have a function that reads a text file and makes a "nivel", it's defined as:

```
void nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(struct nivel * nuevo_nivel, char *nombre_archivo ){
 nuevo_nivel->filas = 0;
 nuevo_nivel->columnas = 0;
 ...
```

I'll post just this part, because it's where the problem resides. I always thought that I could make a function that receives a pointer to the structure and "fill it", so I have a call to the function as this:

```
struct nivel *nuevo_nivel;
nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);
```

Nombre_archivo just holds the name of the text file. When I try to assign a cero to any of the fields of the struct, I get a segmentation fault error. From what I now about pointers, it should work, but I'm afraid I'm missing something here and making a huge mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks everyone! As all of you stated, I was trying to access memory that wasn't allocated, a null pointer. Now I have another problem, but that'll be another post. Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking if `nuevo_nivel` is `NULL` or not? Where is the calling code? If you can provide a small sample of code the compiles and produces the problem that would be helpful.

Comment: @Shafik The code that calls the function is there, the 3rd block code in the post. The error is produced exactly when assigning anything to any field of the struct, in the 1st code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your nuevo_nivel is uninitialized.  You need to allocate it from either the stack or the heap first, like so:

```
// from stack
struct nivel nuevo_nivel;
nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(&nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);

// from heap
struct nivel *nuevo_nivel = malloc(sizeof(nivel));
nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);
```

Which kind of memory you allocate from depends on your scoping/lifetime requirements for nuevo_nivel.

Comment: Oh I see... I must do that inside the function that fills the pointer, right? Because the size of the array is dinamically stablished...

Comment: No, you cannot do that from inside the function, unless you pass the address of the pointer so that you're affecting the caller's value.  Instead, you might consider a "factory" method - change nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo to actually return a nivel *, fully constructed.

Comment: I see :-) now I have some trouble with a "double linked list corrupted" error, but that'll be another post. Thanks!

Comment: Wait a second this post is labelled `C`, how can you use `new`? If this is a C++ answer then we should be passing by reference and so the answer would still be wrong.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Good catch - my C++ bias creeping thru.  I edited the answer to use malloc.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. You have not allocated memory for the structure

```
struct nivel *nuevo_nivel;
nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);
```

It should be

```
 struct nivel *nuevo_nivel;
 //allocate memory
 nuevo_nivel = malloc (sizeof (struct nivel));
 nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your code this way:

```
struct nivel *nuevo_nivel;
nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);
```

but you are not allocating any space for `nuevo_nivel` or at least that is what your code snippet shows. So you are dereferencing a invalid pointer here:

```
nuevo_nivel->filas = 0;
nuevo_nivel->columnas = 0;
```

This would work though:

```
struct nivel nuevo_nivel;
nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(&nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);
```

In this case `nuevo_nivel` will be allocated on the stack and you are taking the address of `nuevo_nivel` using `&`. If you wanted to allocate space inside your function would would have to pass the argument like this `struct nivel ** nuevo_nivel`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not allocated memory `nuevo_nivel`, you declared a pointer to the struct and immediately call `nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(nuevo_nivel,nombre_archivo);`

and inside that function you directly access the struct members (remember no memory allocated yet).  Hence segmentation fault.